# filtering and segmentation of a child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My user can have many questions, however the questions are asked in different frequencies. Like weekly, biweekly, monthly, quarterly. Now I store the frequency of a Question in a QuestionFrequency model. That accepts frequency:string and begins:string.

The values accepted for frequency are:

```
weekly
biweekly
monthly
quarterly
```

now I use this together with the begins to understand the setting. So begins accepts:

- if its biweekly I note down the week number if wants it to start
  (thus I can check if that week number is odd or even)
- if it's monthly it saves "end" or "beginning" thus I can check if its beginning of month with rails.
- quarterly it saves "end" or "beginning"

Thus I can call

```
question.question_frequency.frequency
```

f.ex to get one of the 4 accepted values. Now what I'm trying to do is create a grouped list of all questions that might be available to the User in this week.

I have a method in my user model called all_questions, which job it is to get all questions that is relevant to a user "this" week.

```
  # Collection of Users weekly questions
  def all_questions
    questions
  end
```

now how can I filter "questions" to get things like

```
if biweekly.odd? and Time.zone.now.strftime("%V").odd?
```

then add that question whilst if one is odd || even then we don't want that question this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle it differently.

1. Remove the `QuestionFrequency` model.
2. Add a `frequency` column to `Question` as an integer and use Rails' [Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) method to define the frequency names.
3. Add a `valid_at` date/datetime column to the `Question` model and have it set to the next valid date (either 1 week from now, 2 weeks, 1 month, etc.) depending on the frequency.

Now, once a question is shown to the user (or when it's answered), have the `valid_at` column update for the question according to its frequency:

```
##question.rb example
enum frequency: [:weekly, :biweekly, :monthly]

before_save :update_valid_at

def update_valid_at
  if weekly?
    self[:valid_at] = 1.week.from_now
  elsif biweekly?
    self[:valid_at] = 2.weeks.from_now
  elsif monthly?
    self[:valid_at] = 1.month.from_now
  end
end
```

This way, you can change your `all_questions` to:

```
def all_questions
  questions.where('valid_at < ?', Date.today)
end
```

Comment: I see where you're going, and I'm trying to see how I can adapt it to my use case. Each week a user answers a set of 'answers' that belongs to question. The questions is populated based on if the week is that week to be answered. Here it seems like you're trying to validate the creation of questions?